# Write webcamera video stream into a specified directroy in vps directly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, camera, vps

`ffmpeg` can read webcamera video stream and save it into a file directly.

```
output="/tmp/sample.flv"
ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv -pix_fmt yuv420p  $output
```

`ffmpeg` read my webcamera device `video4linux2` and write the real-time video stream into the file `/tmp/sample.flv`.
Can i write the video stream from webcamera into a specified directory in my vps directly?

I have tried with the bash :

```
ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264  \
       -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv    \
       -pix_fmt yuv420p - | xargs -i ssh {} root@$vps_ip

ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264  \
       -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv    \
       -pix_fmt yuv420p |ssh  root@$vps_ip
```

Both of them can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SSHFS can simplify things

SSHFS allows you to mount a remote directory using SSH.

1. Make target directory on remote host. In this example it is named `remotedir`.
2. Make mount directory on local host. In this example it is named `mountpoint`.
3. Run `sshfs`: `sshfs username@"$vps_ip":remotedir mountpoint`
4. Run `ffmpeg`: `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -vf format=yuv420p mountpoint/output.flv`
5. To unmount `mountpoint` run `fusermount3 -u mountpoint` (Linux) or `umount mountpoint` (macOS).

As for your `ffmpeg` command do not use `-re` with live inputs, and there is no need for `-strict -2`.